# C# - Entity Framework - Build dynamic query from type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently trying to perform a generic query to retrieve all entities from the database which extends a specific class called `Tracker`.

When I retrieve these entities which extend this class:

`public class User : Tracker`

The tracker class looks like this:

```
public class Tracker 
{
    public int? TrackingId { get; set; }
}
```

It basically enforces the class to have the field `TrackingId` however, this could be nullable.

I want to fetch these dynamically so I don't have to list them and if another entity gets added for tracking, then it'll be one place to change it rather than multiple.

When I have this dynamically, I want to query based on the Tracking IS NULL or not.

I am using the following code to retrieve the classes from the assembly.

```cs
var classes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Tracker))
    !.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => type is { IsClass: true, IsAbstract: false } && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Tracker)))
    .ToList();
```

This seems to work well and retrieves the classes, the issue I am having is then looping through this and retrieving it from the database.

```cs
classes.ForEach(clazz =>
{
    var changes = _context.Set<{not sure what goes here?}>(clazz.Name)
        .Where(x => x.TrackingId == null)
        .ToList();
});
```

I have tried to sent the `context.Set<>` to be the Tracker model but as it's not added to the DbSet, it doesn't know what I'm referencing which makes sense.

I don't know if what I'm trying to accomplish it possible, or whether I will have to manually track these or use another package such as Dapper.

EDIT:

I have since tried the following by adding a method onto my DbContext

```
public DbSet<object> Set(string name)
{
  return Set<object>(name);
}
```

I am then calling this:

```
context.Set("Users");
```

However, the set is always null.

Comment: Use the nongeneric set overload that takes a type object. The generic syntax is best for things you know at compiletime and you only know your types at runtime .

Comment: Hi @Ralf can I confirm what you mean by this please?

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect to what I _think_ you are saying.